# SQL grant permission to update just one row at the time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can permission is SQL server be set to specific user to allow update of just one row at the time?
And if answer is `yes`, then how can that be achieved?

E.g. if you have something like this:

```
use MyDB
go 

update t1 set t1.something = 'xxx' 
--select *
from table t1
```

If this select would return more than 1 record to be updated, do not allow that (...or just update first one), otherwise allow it if only one record will be updated.

Comment: Nope. Can't do that. Any particular reason you want to do that ?

Comment: Poorly worded question - if you are trying to say you only want to update if you have more than one row you could do a subquery

Comment: By not letting them update the table directly, but force them to perform data access through a stored procedure, where you could put `TOP 1` or `SET ROWCOUNT` or any other mechanism to limit it...

Comment: @JamesCooke no, completely opposite, I do not want update to be executed if it will affect more then one row. And I don't want to modify the query, I want to have permission (if it's doable) to prevent the user who is writing such a query to do that.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes that will work, however, I was just wondering if it's doable by adjusting the actual permissions which are assigned to the user. I will use that as fallback solution if there's no other way.

Comment: I'm with Aaron here. This is on you as the developer to implement this control. SQL Server isn't equipped to handle this. My recommendation would be a control flow whereby you check the `@@rowcount` when the work is done and rollback if it exceeds your threshold (which I would make interchangeable as part of the proc params).

Comment: use an if statement IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table] <= 1
       UPDATE ....

Comment: if you really want this then yes you can. Write an update trigger and count the numbers in table `inserted` If its larger then 1 then throw an exception. But I do not recommend this, why do you  need this ?

Comment: @GuidoG I need it just to prevent accidental data update on production for the new guy (at least temporarily) :) This idea with trigger seams so far like the best option since the update on that table is not very critical from performance perspective anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a temporary solution, a trigger is a easy way to do this.
This will stop anybody from updating more than one record at a time though.
If you need a permanent solution I would go with the answer of @Larnu

```
create trigger U_YourTableName on dbo.YourTableName
for update
as
begin
     set nocount on

     if (select count(1) from inserted) > 1
     begin
           ;THROW 99001, 'your only allowed one update at a time', 1
     end
end
```

Comment: Good idea/answer. Though I tend to avoid triggers when I can, as I've found them less advantageous from a maintenance perspective and also come with a perf hit.

Comment: @pimbrouwers I agree on the performance hit. About maintenance they can have advantages as well IMHO

Comment: For sure. I simply mean, as the system ages or as new developers are brought on, there is always that level of "forgetfulness". Triggers aren't always immediately apparent. I also prefer the specific sproc approach as it allows the row limit to be configurable at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of answers to this one. One is by means of a trigger, the other is by limiting permissions and using a Stored procedure. Personally, I suggest the SP.

The below sample should explain everything:

```
--Create a sample table and data
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                        SomeString varchar(100));
GO
INSERT INTO SomeTable (SomeString)
VALUES ('adsfasdfad'),
       ('sdafkjsdlf'),
       ('kjlsdahfsldjkhflds');
GO
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable;
GO
--Create a test user, give UPDATE permissions and test
CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
GRANT UPDATE ON SomeTable TO TestUser;
GO
EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';

UPDATE SomeTable
SET SomeString = 'abcdefg'; --this will update every row
GO
REVERT;
GO
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable;
GO
--Trigger technique (not what I recommend)
CREATE TRIGGER LimitToOne ON SomeTable
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) > 1 BEGIN
        --Should raise an error here, but soing a PRINT for speed
        PRINT 'Can''t update more than one row at a time';
    END ELSE BEGIN
        UPDATE ST
        SET SomeString = i.SomeString
        FROM inserted i
             JOIN SomeTable ST On i.ID = ST.ID
    END
GO

UPDATE SomeTable
SET SomeString = '123456'; --this won't work

SELECT *
FROM SomeTable;

UPDATE SomeTable
SET SomeString = '123456'
WHERE ID = 1; --this will work

SELECT *
FROM SomeTable;
GO

--Allow use of SP's only (the better solution, in my opinion)
--Cleanup previous example
DROP TRIGGER LimitToOne;
REVOKE UPDATE ON SomeTable TO TestUser;
GO
--Check we can't update
EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';

UPDATE SomeTable
SET SomeString = 'abcdefg'; --this will fail, as we revoked the permissions
GO
REVERT;
GO
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable;
GO
--Create the SP
CREATE PROC Update_SomeTable @ID int, @String varchar(100) AS

    UPDATE SomeTable
    SET SomeString = @String
    WHERE ID = @ID;
GO
--Give Permissions
GRANT EXECUTE ON Update_SomeTable TO TestUser;
GO
--Test
EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';

EXEC Update_SomeTable 3,'Did this work?'; --Op is forced to only supply one value
GO
REVERT;
GO
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable;

GO
--Clean up
DROP PROC Update_SomeTable;
DROP TABLE SomeTable;
DROP USER TestUser;
```

Of course, the User could update multiple rows sequencially; by use of multiple statements (perhaps by using a `CURSOR` or Dynamic SQL). If you're worried about that, however, you should be providing an application interface and not a login to the person so they can run queries directly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an UPDATE trigger for your table. Grant the user UPDATE permissions for the table and define an UPDATE trigger that checks the username and number of affected records:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.u_yourtable ON dbo.yourtable
FOR UPDATE AS

    IF (ROWCOUNT_BIG() > 1) AND (SUSER_SNAME() IN (N'yourdomain\specificuser'))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('You are not allowed to update more than one record at a time.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server isn't equipped with a way to do this at a security/pemissions level. However, I do believe you can accomplish this with a **stored procedure**. Whereby, you grant the user the ability to do the work through the sproc. Once the work is "done" within the sproc you can check the `@@rowcount`. If this exceeds your threshold, which I would make interchangeable as a parameter, you rollback and raise a user error (5000).

The addition of the limit parameter has the advantage of being configurable at run time from the app tier.

```
create procedure dbo.LimitRecordsChanged
  @NumChangesAllowed int = 1
  --other params
as  
begin

  -- parameter sniffing 
  declare @__NumChangesAllowed int = @NumChangesAllowed;

  begin tran;

  -- do your work here

  if @@rowcount > @__NumChangesAllowed
    rollback;

  commit tran;
end
```